# Explore a COM Object in PHP

Tags: php, com, object, explode, komodo

What would be the proper way to explode a COM object for debugging?  I have a 3rd party function that returns a multilevel object.  The documentation is non existant, so I'd like to be able to echo everything out of the object or debug it in Komodo IDE.

Komodo just says Object and nothing else.  Maybe convert to array?

I know some of the existing options such as `$com->Status`, but there are more variables returned that I'd like to know what they are.

Comment: What to var_dump() / print_r() say?

Comment: `print_r($data) ` returns `variant Object`.  `var_dump` crashes php for some reason.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [com_print_typeinfo()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.com-print-typeinfo.php) instead of var_dump().
This should work for COM, VARIANT and DOTNET objects. The output looks similar to this:

```
class IFile { /* GUID={C7C3F5A4-88A3-11D0-ABCB-00A0C90FFFC0} */

// some PHP-COM internal stuff ...

 /* DISPID=1610612736 */
 function QueryInterface(
  /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$riid,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_PTR [26]  */ &$ppvObj 
  )
 {
 }
 /* DISPID=1610612737 */
 /* VT_UI4 [19] */
 function AddRef(
  )
 {
 }

// ...
 /* DISPID=1610678275 */
 function Invoke(
  /* VT_I4 [3] [in] */ $dispidMember,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$riid,
  /* VT_UI4 [19] [in] */ $lcid,
  /* VT_UI2 [18] [in] */ $wFlags,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [in] --> ? [29]  */ &$pdispparams,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_VARIANT [12]  */ &$pvarResult,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> ? [29]  */ &$pexcepinfo,
  /* VT_PTR [26] [out] --> VT_UINT [23]  */ &$puArgErr 
  )
 {
 }

// properties and methods of the COM object
// ...

 /* DISPID=1001 */
 /* VT_BSTR [8] */
 /* Short name */
 var $ShortName;

 /* DISPID=1004 */
 /* VT_PTR [26] */
 /* Get drive that contains file */
 var $Drive;

 /* DISPID=1005 */
 /* VT_PTR [26] */
 /* Get folder that contains file */
 var $ParentFolder;


// ...

 /* DISPID=1204 */
 function Move(
  /* VT_BSTR [8] [in] */ $Destination 
  )
 {
  /* Move this file */
 }
 /* DISPID=1100 */
 /* VT_PTR [26] */
 function OpenAsTextStream(
  /* ? [29] [in] */ $IOMode,
  /* ? [29] [in] */ $Format 
  )
 {
  /* Open a file as a TextStream */
 }
}
```

Comment: This is a bit late.  But I'll double check this when I revist this project shortly.

Comment: Be careful! `com_print_typeinfo` can make your Apache bugcheck!

Answer (score 0):

It is weird that var_dump didn't work.

But you could try with other of php reflection tools.

[Reflection Class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.construct.php):

```
<?php
Reflection::export(new ReflectionClass(get_class($data)));
?>
```

Or you could try with the [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php):

```
<?php
  print_r(get_class_methods($data));
?>
```

or [get_object_vars](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php) to see its fields:

```
<?php
  print_r(get_object_vars($data));
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: reflection returns `Class [ class variant ] { - Constants [0] { } - Static properties [0] { } - Static methods [0] { } - Properties [0] { } - Methods [0] { } }`.  `print_r(get_class_methods($data));` returns `Array()`.  `print_r(get_objcet_vars($data));` returns function not found

Comment: typo use: get_object_vars   instead of: get_objcet_vars

Answer (score 0):

The native `var_dump()` does not crash for COM objects.

The extension `xdebug`, replaces the native var_debug() function and does not support COM objects.

The solution would be to deactivate the overriding of the function var_dump() by xdebug by adding xdebug.overload_var_dump=off to php.ini.

The related bug in [xdebug bug tracker](http://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=414)